# Switch resources in HTML file depending on environment

Tags: javascript, gulp

I want to swap out JavaScript references in my HTML files depending on a my dev environment. For example, I want to go from this:

```
<!-- dev -->
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

To this

```
<!-- prod -->
<script src="dist/app.min.js"></script>
```

Is there any way to achieve this with Gulp or some other build tool?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [gulp-html-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html-replace) and [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs)

**your-file.html**

```
<!-- build:js -->
<script src="app.js"></script> 
<!-- endbuild -->
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')(),
    args = require('yargs').argv;

    gulp.task('default', function() {
        var filePath = (args.env === 'prod' ? 'dist/app.min.js' : 'app.js')
        return gulp.src('your-file.html')
            .pipe($.htmlReplace({js: filePath}))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
    });
```

`> gulp --env prod` will output dist/your-file.html:

```
<script src="dist/app.min.js"></script>
```

`gulp` will output dist/your-file.html:

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
```